# Solve for $x$: $x^{(x^n)}=n$

Tags: algebra-precalculus, logarithms

$x^{(x^n)}=n$ . Solve for $x$. I tried using logarithms however I got stuck with $n \log(x \log x) = \log ( \log n)$. Can someone explain the solution to this equation?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Raising both sides to the $n$th power gives $$(x^n)^{x^n}=n^n,$$ so $$x^n=n$$ and $$x=\sqrt[n]{n}.$$ For $n<1$, there's a second solution, though.

Answer (score 1):

Use the Lambert $W$ function https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lambert_W_function.

If $ze^z=y$ then $z=W(y)$.

Take $ \ln $ of your equation and multiply by $n$
\begin{eqnarray*}
x^n \ln (x^n) =n \ln n \\
e^{\ln x^n} \ln (x^n) =n \ln n \\
n \ln x = W( n \ln n) \\
x = \exp(\frac{1}{n}  W( n \ln n)).
\end{eqnarray*}
Now use $W( n \ln n)= \ln n$ and we have $ \color{blue}{x= n^{\frac{1}{n}}}$. (Which I would not have got if I had not seen Professor Vector's answer $\ddot  \smile$)

Comment: For $n<1$, you get two solutions, because $W(x)$ has two real branches for $-1/e\le x\le0$. If $n=1/2$, I get only $x=1/4$, while you also get $x=1/16$.

Answer (score 0):

$x^{(x^n)}=n$, so $x^n = \frac{\log n}{\log x}$.

I suppose $n \geq 1$.

There is no solution for x<1.

While $x^n$ is increasing for all x>1, $\frac{\log n}{\log x}$ is decreasing for all x>1. So there is only one solution for x>1 (see Professor Vector's post).

Answer (score 0):

I think it means that $n\in\mathbb N$.

If $n=1$ we need to solve $x^x=1$, which gives $x=1$.

Let $n>1$ and $f(x)=x^{x^n}$.

Thus, it's obvious that for $0<x\leq1$ our equation has no roots.

But for $x>1$ we see that $f$ increases.

Thus, our equation has one root maximum.

Easy to see that $\sqrt[n]{n}$ is a root.

Id est, it's an unique root and we are done!

Answer (score 0):

so if $x^{x^n}=n$ and you take the natural log of both sides you get $x^n * ln(abs(x))=ln(abs(n))$ so then assuming x>0 and x>0 I get $x^n * ln(x) = ln(n)$ and then multiply both sides of the equation by n and you would get $x^n * n * ln(x) = ln(n)*n$ and using the rule that $ln(a)*b=ln(a^b)$ would give us $x^n * ln(x^n) = ln(n^n)$ and then using the rule that $e^{ln(c)} = c$ we would get $e^{ln(x^n)} * ln(x^n) = ln(n^n)$ and using the property of the Lambert W function that $W(e^d * d)=d$ and taking the Lambert W function of both sides gives you $ln(x^n) = W(ln(n^n))$ so using the rule that $ln(a)*b=ln(a^b)$ gives us $n*ln(x)=W(ln(n^n))$ and dividing both sides by n gives us $ln(x)=W(ln(n^n))/n$ which using the property that if $ln(s)=t$ that then $s=e^t$ gives us $x=e^{(W(ln(n^n))/n)}$ for $x>0$